# Why is the order of UILayoutGuide in subviews array not consistent?

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout

Sometimes the two `UILayoutGuides` in the `subviews` array are at the end of the array, sometimes not. If I'm trying to make a view appear right behind the topmost view, this inconsistency is very problematic!

It might be an Xcode bug because one day, everything was fine, the next day there were two extra subviews and I adjusted, the next day mixed results. So - does it depend on some kind of setting or is this a bug? It would be nice not to have to filter the `subview` array or inspect the `Class` of the `subview` or inspect if `conformsToProtocol:UILayoutSupport` just to do this.

from my console:

```
(lldb) po [onView subviews]
<__NSArrayM 0x1708426d0>(
<UIView: 0x1701750c0; frame = (0 69; 768 887); autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer:     0x17022e2c0>>,
<UIView: 0x170175180; frame = (0 0; 768 69); autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x17022e3e0>>,
<UIView: 0x178173740; frame = (0 956; 768 68); autoresize = TM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x1782375a0>>,
<_UILayoutGuide: 0x170198e20; frame = (0 0; 0 0); hidden = YES; layer = <CALayer: 0x17022e660>>,
<_UILayoutGuide: 0x170199570; frame = (0 1024; 0 0); hidden = YES; layer = <CALayer: 0x17022e680>>
)
```

But like I said, sometimes these are not at the end of the array.

And I am starting to think this is not an Xcode bug because I just restarted it and get the same results.

For now, I have implemented this method so that I can call lastObject on it and get the right non-UILayoutGuide subview. Be sure not to use fast-enumeration here because that does not guarantee the order of objects in the receiver array.

```
- (id)filteredSubviews:(UIView *)onView
{
    NSMutableArray *filteredSubviews = [@[] mutableCopy];
    for (int i = 0; i < onView.subviews.count; i++) 
    {
        id subview = onView.subviews[i];
        if ([subview isMemberOfClass:[UIView class]])
        {
            [filteredSubviews addObject:subview];
        }
    }

    return filteredSubviews;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Layout guides are not views and should not be treated as such!** It's an implementation detail and you should not rely on it for your view layout logic. Traversing the `subviews` array is also not considered good practice, because the system may add subviews there which may not be ones that you expect (surprise, it already did!).

You should keep track of which view is top most, and use `insertSubview:belowSubview:` to add subviews at the correct position in the hierarchy.

Comment: I understand that they are not views. I ended up doing what you suggested (as you were suggesting it, apparently. lol). But that's such a pain! Lol. There's not a better way? Also, did this change recently, because it was all working fine before.

Comment: What is a pain? Keeping track of the top view? Seems very easy to me. ;-)

Comment: Well, the thing is...I have a utility class that is doing this (adding a customized replacement for UIAlert). Some views have footers and some do not, so I need to check the view hierarchy so that it can nicely slide up from behind the footer...but only if there's a footer, obviously. So I'm not in the view from view.subviews at the time this is happening. ...but that's beside the point. I have solved the problem, but I want to know if something changed recently because I didn't used to have this problem until a couple weeks ago. Thank you!

Comment: Usually the layout guides are on the back of the view hierarchy (so the first objects in the array). Not sure why for you they are on top.